# Varnish histogram showing late hits

Tags: varnish

Is there an explanation for having so many hits so late ?

Here it's just after a varnish reload (debian 10 varnish 6.1.1)

```
1:10, n = 1485, d = 1                                      

                                             |
200_                                         |
                                             |
                                             ||
                                             ||
                                             ||
150_                                         ||
                                             ||
                                            ||#
                    |                       #|#  #
                    | |                     ###  #
100_                | |                    ####  #
                    | |                    ####  #
                   ||||                    ####  ##
                   ||||                    ####  ##
                   ||||                    ####  ##
50_                |||||                   ####  ##
                   |||||                   #### |##
                   |||||                   #### ###
                   |||||  #                #### ###
                   ||||||##               |####|###
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
|1e-6   |1e-5   |1e-4   |1e-3   |1e-2   |1e-1   |1e0    |1e1    |1e2
```

Having 2 or 3 happens, I assumed it's when receiving requests on same url while a backend fetch is happening. Is that right?

I'm suspecting could be actually be grace hits period and indicating Hit at the time of completed background fetch (is_bgfetch).  Is it true?

But so many I never seen before.

I can't spot any hits that took more then 4ms (got nginx logging this at frontend) so I shouldn't be too worried, but this happens just after I did a big big refactoring of a complex setup so I'm freeking out ö

Tx

Answer (score 1):

The default profile is `responsetime`, so it just looks like you are seeing a lot of misses, and are going to the backend a lot.

By default, the grouping is `request`, and grace is going to trigger an asynchronous fetch that will not delay the `Process` time, so it can't be that.